# Search Android phone contacts cursor adapter + cyrillic sensitive

Tags: android, database, sqlite, contacts, android-cursoradapter

I want to make my Android RecyclerView Cursor adapter non sensitive using cyrillic. Everything is ok but no reaction at all when I am printing any of cyrillic symbols. My Sql request is next:

```
@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
    String value = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
    String selection = "LOWER("+ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+") LIKE '" + value + "%' ";
    Cursor cursor = app().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, null, SqlCursorLoader.DATE_SORT_ORDER_ASC);
    results.values = cursor;
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Please supply more information such as Data and Table structure, so that others can reproduce your problem.

Comment: table is standard phonebook ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, i'm trying to make insensitive search in contacts phone book